# Overcomplicated Tic Tac Toe menu

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm creating a Tic Tac Toe game with AI, with 3 difficulty levels. In order to play (or watch computer vs computer) you have to input a command that will start the game with wanted AI levels. This is my code for the main function:

```
def main():
    while True:
        command = input('Input command: ')
        if command == 'start user easy':
            game = Easy()
            game.easy_pvc()
        elif command == 'start easy easy':
            game = Easy()
            game.easy_cvc()
        elif command == 'start easy user':
            game = Easy()
            game.easy_cvp()
        elif command == 'start user user':
            game = Grid()
            game.pvp()
        elif command == 'start user medium':
            game = Medium()
            game.medium_pvc()
        elif command == 'start medium user':
            game = Medium()
            game.medium_cvp()
        elif command == 'start medium easy':
            game = Medium()
            game.medium_easy_cvc()
        elif command == 'start easy medium':
            game = Medium()
            game.easy_medium_cvc()
        elif command == 'start medium medium':
            game = Medium()
            game.medium_cvc()
        elif command == 'exit':
            exit()
        else:
            print('Bad parameters!')
```

I think this is a mess and can be simplified, but I am not sure how to do that. I am going to add difficulty hard, so there will be a lot of possibilites to input these commands, which means a lot of code.

Comment: can't you refactor your function easy_* , medium_* to only one with different parameter thus you will only adapt those parameters

Answer (score 0):

You could use something to like the module cmd to add autocomplete and that uses functions for example

```py
import cmd
class input_shell(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
       super(input_shell, self).__init__()

    def do_start(self, line):
       #Do something
       pass

    def complete_start(self, text, line, start_index, end_index):
        start_wordlist = ["easy", "medium", "hard"]
        if text:
            return [
                words for words in start_wordlist
                if words.startswith(text)
            ]
        else:
            return start_wordlist

if __name__ == '__main__':
   shell = input_shell()
   shell.cmdloop()
```

This allows for a much better user experience and cleaner to read if familiar with the CMD module
Read more about the cmd module here https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a `str.split` function to split the response into a list.

```
player_types = ["user", "easy", "medium", "hard"]


def main():
    while True:
        command = input('Input command: ')
        command_list = command.split()
        if (len(command_list) == 3 and command_list[0] == "start" # checks if the response is an appropriate length, and whether it starts with a 'start' command
           and all(i in player_types for i in command_list[1:])): # checks if the response uses valid player types
            game = Game()
            game.start(command_list[1], command_list[2]) 
        else:
            print("Invalid command")
```

I've assumed you can implement a function `game.start` in a Game class that takes two strings corresponding to player types, and initializes a game using those kinds of players. If the game interface has to be like you described, there isn't a simpler solution than yours.